# fprintf generates valgrind error

Tags: c, printf, valgrind

I have problem with the following code:

```c
#define NTHREADS 100

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];

    // ...

    // Create threads
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, thread, NULL);
    }

    debugln("All %u threads are ready", NTHREADS);

    // ...

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    debugln("All threads terminated");

    return 0;
}
```

Where `debugln` is defined as follow:

```c
#define debugln(_fmt, _args...) fprintf(stderr, _fmt "\n", ##_args)
```

**The problem:**

When executing the program with `NTHREADS` set to `100` then `valgrind` outputs this error multiple times:

```c
==2780== Invalid write of size 4
==2780==    at 0x50976A2: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:246)
==2780==    by 0x509CE53: buffered_vfprintf (vfprintf.c:2313)
==2780==    by 0x509788D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1316)
==2780==    by 0x50A24E6: fprintf (fprintf.c:33)
==2780==    by 0x400ACA: main (in /tmp/cbuild_1413987921)
==2780==  Address 0x7feffd158 is on thread 1's stack
```

But when I change `debugln` to

```c
#define debugln(_fmt, _args...) printf(_fmt "\n", ##_args)
```

then the error vanishes.

I did already try `flockfile` & `funlockfile` and increasing the stacksize. Both did not fix the error. BTW `valgrind --version` gives `valgrind-3.7.0`

**EDIT**

The error gets away when changing

`#define NTHREADS 100`

to

`const unsigned NTHREADS = 100;`

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Have you already tried to take the macro out of the equation, i.e. making the `fprintf()` / `printf()` calls directly?

Comment: @DevSolar Get the same result. :/

Comment: Try `%lu`.  There may be a size mismatch.

Comment: @dohashi Gives me gcc error `type mismatch`.

Comment: @d3l: Interesting to know. Then why does your question include code that is not necessary to reproduce the error? ;-) It confuses the issue.

Comment: @d3l strip down your code to a minimum that still produces the error.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I already did, its enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: @d3i just curious, try to remove the call to `pthread_create` and see what happens. BTW what does `thread` do ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Already did, it only occurs when `NTHREADS` is set to `100`

Comment: @d3l: "**minimum** code that still produces the error" != "**enough** code to produce the error". Reducing the code is a very essential step in debugging. Not *having* a minimal set indicates you posted here before you used all the debugging techniques at your disposal, requiring *everyone* wanting to help you to check, and rule out, the macro (or the use of pthreads) as cause of the error. Multiple effort, wasted time.

Comment: What datatype is pthread_t on your system? ... which may explain your problem.

Comment: @DevSolar the thread does not anything at all. Its implemented like this `void *thread(void *ctx) { return NULL; }`.

Comment: Your `%u` format specifier is wrong, use `%d` to print and `int`, or add the suffix `U` to your constant.